# Simultaneous Display Of Text From One TextArea To Another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Actually I am a newbie to javascript and i wanted to display text written in one textarea in another textarea.

i did refer to the question [Simultaneously write text from one Textarea to another Textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10133378/simultaneously-write-text-from-one-textarea-to-another-textarea)

I saw it in jsfiddle but i am not understanding how to merge this code.

I have gone this far uptil now:

```
    <html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>


</head>
<body>
    <script src="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
    // put your Javascript here
      $('.one').on('keydown', function(event){
             var key = String.fromCharCode(event.which);
             if (!event.shiftKey) {
             key = key.toLowerCase();
             }
                 $('.two').val( $(this).val() + key );
    });
});


    </script>

        <textarea class="one"></textarea>
        <textarea class="two"></textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

I am not understanding what is the problem.

Comment: Works fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/2udGB/. Have you checked the console for errors?

Comment: What exactly isn't working as expected? http://jsfiddle.net/LRTV7/