# how to use a function inside a function in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
<table>
    <tbody id="add_weight" >
        <tr></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<a onClick="maira()" >+Add more Weights.</span></a>
```

here i am having a anchor tag..i have called a function when user clicks on anchor tag..that is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var b=1;
function maira()
{
    if(b==10)
    {
        alert("can't Add more than 10 Weight Rates");
        return false;
    }

    var table=document.getElementById("add_weight")
    var row=table.insertRow(b);
    var cell1=row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2=row.insertCell(1);

    cell1.innerHTML="<input type='text' id='rate"+b+"' name='rate"+b+"' onkeyup='alert(hi)'/>";
    cell2.innerHTML="<input type='text' id='flat"+b+"' name='flat"+b+"' />";

    b=b+1;  
}
</script>
```

here when a user clicks a new row gets added with two fields namely rate and flat....this is working fine now the problem is that...i want when user enters anything in flat textbox than it should come simultaneously in rate textbox...probably using onkeyup even...can anyone help me with this??

Comment: Check this SO post, [simultaneously-write-text-from-one-textarea-to-another-textarea](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10133378/simultaneously-write-text-from-one-textarea-to-another-textarea)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a class to attach event handler or attach handlers individually.
But you'll have to use data- attribute to store the index of the row, so that the handler can know the index and the "id" of the target element in which you want to copy the text

Answer (score 0):

Attach event handler to your `class/id`. You can go with any `libraries` or below utility code would work fine. You are `attaching` the element to `onkeyup` event.

```
function addEvent(element, evnt, funct){
  if (element.attachEvent)
   return element.attachEvent('on'+evnt, funct);
  else
   return element.addEventListener(evnt, funct, false);
}

// example
addEvent(
    document.getElementById('myElement'),
    'keyup',
    function () { alert('hi!'); } // update your other text field value.
);
```

Here is a working `fiddle` for you.

http://jsfiddle.net/bmArj/