# How to use two textareas simultaneously

Tags: javascript, textarea

I have two textareas with fixed width and height:

`<textarea id="t1"></textarea>`
`<textarea id="t2"></textarea>`

So what I want is when the text in `#t1` overflows, the rest text should automatically go into `#t2`

Comment: So, have you tried anything?

Comment: i recommand you check this solutions,link :
[1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10133378/simultaneously-write-text-from-one-textarea-to-another-textarea

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Khadija the link is about duplicating textarea, but my question is to extend it